# What is the difference between an exact differential and a total differential?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Some intuition here may be helpful. If you care you can use the formula for the equation of a volume V= pr*r^2h   where the x, y  variables are nothing more that the height and radius.  The book said this would be an example of an exact differential.  BUT I don't see any difference between this and a total differential but there must be...can someone turn this example into one that now demonstrates both a total differential and an unexact differential?  I am looking for the intuition so I can spot the difference between the three when working through the examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe we can look at it like this ...  Consider the equation
$$
d(x^2y) = 2xy\;dx + x^2\;dy
\tag{1}$$

**Problem 1.**  Compute the total differential of $x^2 y$.  Solution: write down (1).

**Problem 2.**  Is $2xy\;dx + x^2\;dy$ an exact differential?  Solution: Yes.  Proof: (1).

So, as you say, in a certain sense they are the same.  But the point of view is different.  In  Problem 1, we start with the function and compute its differential.  In Problem 2, we start with the differential, and find the function.

In fact, in Problem 2 there are ways to answer "Yes" without finding the function.  Instead we can compute
$$
\frac{\partial(2xy)}{\partial y} = 2x
\\
\frac{\partial(x^2)}{\partial x} = 2x
$$
and these are equal, so $2xy\;dx + x^2\;dy$ is an exact differential.

Comment: wonderful job ...should I assume that if the second condition is not true then it would be considered an un exact differential?  I assume the unexact differential is still a derivative of something otherwise it would not be called a differential but it lacks this second property?

Comment: If unequal I would say $2xy\;dx + x^2\;dy$ is not exact.  That means it is not the differential of any function.  But (in more advanced mathematics) we still call it "a differential" or maybe "a differential form".

Comment: yeh ...I noticed that ...I think that's what threw me for a loop. Probably mathematicians have a very good reason to call in a "differential" form..  . But for stupid people like me that can be all it takes to confuse me.  But you straightened me out. thanx